# Sharepoint: display plain text field as html

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint list, where one of the columns is plain text - Description. When you edit a list item, Description field is normally a TextArea. I have it programmed that this TextArea is extended with JavaScript to accept rich text (html really), so I have my custom rich text field. The problem is that when I input the rich data everything looks fine but when I save the edited item and then display it, the text is displayed as plain text, not html, so instead of a bold text I get "< b >text< /b >". And I would like it to be displayed as html. What can I do with it?

Edit: I don't want to use the built-in editor, because I need some different behavious.

Answer (score 2):

The code that reads in the text input from the form and saves it to the list will be doing a [HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spencode.htmlencode.aspx) operation that replaces

```
< with &lt;
> with &gt;
```

and so on (look at the source of the page after a save)

This occurs 'server side' so you won't be able to change this using JavaScript.

You've got two options I think

- As F5 mentioned you can create a [custom field type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx) with your own behaviour for rendering and update. This is the 'correct' way to do this.
- You could change your funky javascript to work on a rich text field, hack into the rendering of the built in RTE and replace it with your own.

Of cource as soon as you are taking input from a user and then rendering it back to your web page you open yourself up to all sorts of nasties such as [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) if you are not filtering out potential bad stuff (the very reason why the HtmlEncode is used) - less of a problem in a typical SharePoint site on an Intranet than a public facing site.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports rich text columns using its own in-built editor.  You just have to change the column settings so it allows rich text.

If you are using a JavaScript editor because of browser compatability with the built-in rich text editor then SharePoint will always strip the html from whatever is entered as it expects the input to be plain text.

**Re your comments**

If you want the field to display in rich text it needs to be a rich text field, by setting it to plain text you are always going to lose your custom formatting.

You need to look into [custom field types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So where exactly are the data being displayed incorrectly: on the List Display Form or on a Page Layout? If it's on the Page Layout the fix is easy: create a custom Field Control which will retrieve the value of the field (like SPContext.Current.ListItem["YourField"]) and decode the contents to get HTML instead of encoded HTML entities.